# How to install mongodb client inside docker alpine?

Tags: alpine-linux

I tried to test whether the URL of MongoDB (client connection string) is correct in the server, it uses Kubernetes with alpine docker, when I tried to install clients, it shows:

```
bash-5.0# apk add mongodb-client
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  mongodb-client (missing):
    required by: world[mongodb-client]
bash-5.0# apk add  mongodb-tools 
ERROR: unsatisfiable constraints:
  mongodb-tools (missing):
    required by: world[mongodb-tools]
```

How to install MongoDB-client only in alpine? usually, I use `apk add MySQL-client` in but what's the MongoDB client only package?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found easiest way using NodeJS (easier than with Ruby or others)

```
apk add nodejs
apk add npm
npm install mongo
node
```

then you can connect as usual:

```
const {MongoClient} = require('mongodb');
let c = (new MongoClient('mongodb://user:pass@host:port/dbname?connectTimeoutMS=1000&wtimeoutMS=1000')).connect()
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me within an Alpine container:

```
/ # echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/main >> /etc/apk/repositories
/ # echo http://dl-cdn.alpinelinux.org/alpine/v3.6/community >> /etc/apk/repositories
/ # apk add mongodb mongodb-tools
/ # mongo mongodb://MY-HOST:27017
MY-HOST:PRIMARY>
```

Comment: `mongodb` is [still available](https://pkgs.alpinelinux.org/packages?name=mongodb&branch=v3.9&repo=&arch=x86_64&maintainer=) in Alpine Linux 3.9.

Comment: this worked for me, thanks a lot mate,